# Invalid token using Auth0 token to a .net backend and a next.js frontend

Tags: c#, next.js, jwt, auth0

I'm using Auth0 to validate requests to a .net core backend api.  No matter what I do I can't get the tokens passed to the .net core backend validated.  I get Bearer error="invalid_token" from the .net core backend using the [Authorize] filter.

How I'm setting the access token on the request to the backend(next.js middleware)

```
const user = await getSession(req, res);
const requestHeaders = new Headers(req.headers);
    requestHeaders.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${user.accessToken}`);
    const response = NextResponse.next({ request: { headers: requestHeaders } });
    return response;
```

Config on the .net core backend

```
var domain = $"https://{builder.Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/";
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
    options.Authority = domain;
    options.Audience = builder.Configuration["Auth0:Audience"];
});
```

Things I've tried and confirmed

- Confirmed the authorize header is correctly included in the request
- Followed the Auth0 example nearly exactly for config on the .net backend

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Feel like I'm banging my head against a wall and getting nowhere!

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you using the audience parameter to get an access token? You need to if you want the access token to be a JWT. Otherwise, it'll just be an opaque token.

Comment: @MattRaible I'm using the getSession from @auth0/nextjs-auth0/edge.  Where would I get the token using the audience param?

Comment: Usually the error description also indicates the reason (e.g., "The audience is invalid", "The signature is invalid", etc.). What is your description?

Note that the audience must exactly match the value recorded in the dashboard, including any trailing slashes